# How to set multiple STATIC_URL for the same static data?

Tags: django, django-staticfiles

An already developed front end is making calls to the same static data files using different URLs

```
GET /static/images/1.png
```

and also using sometimes this:

```
GET /SomeDirName/static/images/1.png
```

Setting my STATIC_URL to "/static/" serve only the requests similar to the first example.
Is it possible to redirect the GET from the second example? Or how can I handle it?

Please note that Im not asking how to set STATICFILES_DIRS.

Comment: The reason that this works on a different path is because you do *not* use a *leading* slash, so you make requests to `static/images/1.png`, instead of `/static/images/1.png`. Do you use the  `{% static ... %}` template tag?

Comment: What does the "already developed front end" code issuing those requests look like ? Is this served with django views and templates ? Is it a totaly different tuff (react or angualr or whatever) ?

Comment: You're not understanding the role of `STATIC_URL`. In production, its sole purpose is to specify the prefix for all static files urls when using `{% static 'path/to/file.png' %}` in your template. It does not help to "serve" anything since it's your web server that serves your files. Only in development it also tells the Django web server when a request corresponds to a static files request.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Instead of implementing a redirection mechanism, I strongly advise to solve the problem "*upstream*". The reason it aims to fetch the files with `somedirname/static/images/1.png` is because you do *not* use a *leading slash* in your URL. So you wrote something like:

```
<img src="static/images/1.png">
```

instead of:

```
<img src="/static/images/1.png">
```

It is however *strongly* advisable to use the [**`{% static … %}`** template tag [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/#std:templatetag-static) and thus implement this as:

```
{% load static %}
<img src="{% static 'images/1.png' %}">
```

This will automatically generate the correct URL. If you later change the [**`STATIC_URL`** setting [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/settings/#static-url), it will prepend the other `STATIC_URL` to the path, and thus make the use of static files more flexible.

Comment: the front is already written, and I cant change it now.
It should be tecnically possible to serve same files with different URLs w/o having to redirect the request for each single existing file right?

Comment: @Hangon: well first of all Django does *not* serve files in production, so any mechanism in Django should eventually be replaced with an apache/nginx/... system. Furthermore it would result in a huge amount of ambiguous urls. For example `someapp/<path:my_path>` would take `someapp/static/images/1.png` as well (with `my_path` being `'static/images/1.png'`). The last thing you want is making ambiguous url. Ideally every file is servered through one path, and every path serves exactly one view.

Comment: By making it a non-injective/non-surjective relation, you generate a lot of future trouble. Like people who can not see their pages (because their username is `"static"` for example). As one of my professors once said: in engineering there is a fundamental law: the law of conservation of misery.